# BinaryReader.ReadUInt16() is very slow

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I have just profiled my application and I am reading a memory stream using ReadUInt16(). It is very costly on time. Is there an alternative - or any way to speed it up?

**Edit**

Sorry, I made a mistake, although I was running the application not in debug mode, my properties were not set to 64-bit CPU and Active (release) - changing to these speeds thing up inordinately!

Comment: How slow is very slow, and can you post your code on how you profiled it?

Comment: `ReadUInt16` shouldn't be any slower than any of the other `Read...` methods provided by `BinaryReader`, once you've taken into account data length etc. Are you asking for an alternative to `BinaryReader` itself? If so, then you'll need to provide more details about what exactly you're trying to do.